# Toggle (Add/Remove) keyboard language (1 cmd)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two .cmd (bat) files to add/remove keyboard (input) language:

LangAdd.cmd:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangAdd.xml"
```

LangRemove.cmd:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangRemove.xml"
```

LangAdd.xml:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<gs:InputPreferences> 
<gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0412:{A028AE76-01B1-46C2-99C4-ACD9858AE02F}{B5FE1F02-D5F2-4445-9C03-C568F23C99A1}"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

LangRemove.xml:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<gs:InputPreferences> 
<gs:InputLanguageID Action="remove" ID="0412:{A028AE76-01B1-46C2-99C4-ACD9858AE02F}{B5FE1F02-D5F2-4445-9C03-C568F23C99A1}"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

But I'd like to use only one cmd file - toggle add/remove language

How can I do it?

Comment: languages are stored in the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard` so I can just use statements if...else to check if language is already added. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used if..else statements:

```
IF EXIST REG QUERY "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /d 00000412 (
    control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangRemove.xml" 
) ELSE ( 
    control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangAdd.xml"
)
```